# Solving equation $x \sin x = a$

Tags: trigonometry

So, the equation is in the title. Is there a way to solve it in radicals or/and elementary functions?

It's an even function $f(x) = x \sin x$ with minimums and maximums not lying on lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$. I've tried to manipulate with its complex representation, but found nothing interesting about it.

Comment: This equation does not have a nice closed form solution using radicals and elementary functions. You will need numerical methods for each value of $a$,

Comment: Is there any evidence that there's no such solutions?

Comment: I don't know of a formal proof that there is no such solution but I am sure there is a theorem in the literature that implies it. It would take more time than I want to spend to find a reference. That proof is likely to be hard to follow at an elementary level. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closed-FormSolution.html

Comment: @WhiteBlackGoose Only numerical solution for such transcendental equations arising out of the symmetric functions is possible.  Solutions are of  both signs $(\pm)$  real and complex conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

There are obvious "nice" solutions, specifically:

$a=0$ where $x=n\pi, n\in \mathbb{Z}$

and $a = (4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2},n\in \mathbb{Z}$ where $x= \pm a$

Apart from these there is probably no exact solution that can be expressed in terms of the standard elementary functions. This is as @EthanBolker has expressed in the comments.

I am not knowledgeable about the theory required to prove that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you may be concerned by the first zero of function
$$f(x)=x \sin(x)-a$$ assuming $0 \leq a \leq \frac \pi 2$, what you could do is to use the usual series expansion that is to say
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1)!}x^{2(n+1)}-a$$ and use series reversion to get something like
$$x=\sqrt a \left(1+\frac{a}{12}+\frac{29 a^2}{1440}+\frac{263 a^3}{40320}+\frac{23479
   a^4}{9676800}+O\left(a^5\right) \right)$$
Trying for a few values, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.318929 &  0.318929 \\
 0.2 & 0.455052 &  0.455053 \\
 0.3 & 0.562516 &  0.562517 \\
 0.4 & 0.655879 &  0.655886 \\
 0.5 & 0.740813 &  0.740841 \\
 0.6 & 0.820277 &  0.820357 \\
 0.7 & 0.896081 &  0.896278 \\
 0.8 & 0.969460 &  0.969899 \\
 0.9 & 1.041330 &  1.042232 \\
 1.0 & 1.112421 &   1.114157 \\
 1.1 & 1.183338 &   1.186529 \\
 1.2 & 1.254616 &   1.260274 \\
 1.3 & 1.326741 &   1.336512 \\
 1.4 & 1.400169 &   1.416772 \\
 1.5 & 1.475340 &   1.503412
\end{array}
\right)$$ To polish the root, start Newton method with the estimate.

For example, for $a=1.5$, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.4753402 \\
 1 & 1.5029586 \\
 2 & 1.5034118 \\
 3 & 1.5034119
\end{array}
\right)$$